# After install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017 and build project, project not work

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssms

Vusual Studio 2017 installed. After install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017 (together with her install Visual Studio 2015 shell (isolated)) and build project, project could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.PerformanceProvider, Version=14.0.0.0.
After remove Visual Studio 2015 shell (isolated) and rebuild, project work. How can I fix this?

Comment: I can suggest to repair from vs installer

Comment: Repair Visual Studio does not help.